# How to center an SVG graphic in its container div

Tags: css, svg

I am designing a custom **Sign in with Google** button.

It looks like the following:

[image]

As you can see, the Google logo with the white background is not vertically centered.

How can I vertically center it in the blue container box?

I want the final result to look like the following:

[image]

The code snippets are as follows:

**login.svg (Located in the public folder)**

```
<svg width="46px" height="46px" viewBox="0 0 46 46" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
    <!-- Generator: Sketch 3.3.3 (12081) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
    <title>btn_google_dark_normal_ios</title>
    <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
    <defs>
        <filter x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="filter-1">
            <feOffset dx="0" dy="1" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1"></feOffset>
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0.5" in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1"></feGaussianBlur>
            <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0.168 0" in="shadowBlurOuter1" type="matrix" result="shadowMatrixOuter1"></feColorMatrix>
            <feOffset dx="0" dy="0" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter2"></feOffset>
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0.5" in="shadowOffsetOuter2" result="shadowBlurOuter2"></feGaussianBlur>
            <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0.084 0" in="shadowBlurOuter2" type="matrix" result="shadowMatrixOuter2"></feColorMatrix>
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode in="shadowMatrixOuter1"></feMergeNode>
                <feMergeNode in="shadowMatrixOuter2"></feMergeNode>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
        <rect id="path-2" x="0" y="0" width="40" height="40" rx="2"></rect>
        <rect id="path-3" x="5" y="5" width="38" height="38" rx="1"></rect>
    </defs>
    <g id="Google-Button" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
        <g id="9-PATCH" sketch:type="MSArtboardGroup" transform="translate(-608.000000, -219.000000)"></g>
        <g id="btn_google_dark_normal" sketch:type="MSArtboardGroup" transform="translate(-1.000000, -1.000000)">
            <g id="button" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup" transform="translate(4.000000, 4.000000)" filter="url(#filter-1)">
            </g>
            <g id="button-bg-copy">
                <use fill="#FFFFFF" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" xlink:href="#path-3"></use>
                <use fill="none" xlink:href="#path-3"></use>
                <use fill="none" xlink:href="#path-3"></use>
                <use fill="none" xlink:href="#path-3"></use>
            </g>
            <g id="logo_googleg_48dp" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup" transform="translate(15.000000, 15.000000)">
                <path d="M17.64,9.20454545 C17.64,8.56636364 17.5827273,7.95272727 17.4763636,7.36363636 L9,7.36363636 L9,10.845 L13.8436364,10.845 C13.635,11.97 13.0009091,12.9231818 12.0477273,13.5613636 L12.0477273,15.8195455 L14.9563636,15.8195455 C16.6581818,14.2527273 17.64,11.9454545 17.64,9.20454545 L17.64,9.20454545 Z" id="Shape" fill="#4285F4" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
                <path d="M9,18 C11.43,18 13.4672727,17.1940909 14.9563636,15.8195455 L12.0477273,13.5613636 C11.2418182,14.1013636 10.2109091,14.4204545 9,14.4204545 C6.65590909,14.4204545 4.67181818,12.8372727 3.96409091,10.71 L0.957272727,10.71 L0.957272727,13.0418182 C2.43818182,15.9831818 5.48181818,18 9,18 L9,18 Z" id="Shape" fill="#34A853" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
                <path d="M3.96409091,10.71 C3.78409091,10.17 3.68181818,9.59318182 3.68181818,9 C3.68181818,8.40681818 3.78409091,7.83 3.96409091,7.29 L3.96409091,4.95818182 L0.957272727,4.95818182 C0.347727273,6.17318182 0,7.54772727 0,9 C0,10.4522727 0.347727273,11.8268182 0.957272727,13.0418182 L3.96409091,10.71 L3.96409091,10.71 Z" id="Shape" fill="#FBBC05" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
                <path d="M9,3.57954545 C10.3213636,3.57954545 11.5077273,4.03363636 12.4404545,4.92545455 L15.0218182,2.34409091 C13.4631818,0.891818182 11.4259091,0 9,0 C5.48181818,0 2.43818182,2.01681818 0.957272727,4.95818182 L3.96409091,7.29 C4.67181818,5.16272727 6.65590909,3.57954545 9,3.57954545 L9,3.57954545 Z" id="Shape" fill="#EA4335" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
                <path d="M0,0 L18,0 L18,18 L0,18 L0,0 Z" id="Shape" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
            </g>
            <g id="handles_square" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup"></g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="customBtn">
      <img src="login.svg" />
      <div className="buttonText">Sign in with Google</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**index.css**

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.customBtn {
  margin: 10rem;
  width: 19rem;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #4285f4;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  position: relative;
}

.buttonText {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 30%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with flex.

Add to `.customBtn` class this styles:

```css
.customBtn {
    ...your style

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Nope. Not getting the desired result.

Comment: Sorry, i misread your issue. I read fast _"the button"_ not _"the logo"_ inside it.  I'll try again

Comment: Men, your code give a centered logo. I replay your HTML and CSS and give a centered one. BUT, I don't have exact button as your first one, maybe you have some other styles outside this component making some noice.  
Could you give us the _"Computed"_ version of your de-centered container and logo?

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.customBtn {
  background-color: #4285f4;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.buttonText {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<button class="customBtn">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="46" height="46"><defs><filter id="a" width="200%" height="200%" x="-50%" y="-50%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox"><feOffset dy="1" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1"/><feGaussianBlur in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" stdDeviation=".5"/><feColorMatrix in="shadowBlurOuter1" result="shadowMatrixOuter1" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.168 0"/><feOffset in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter2"/><feGaussianBlur in="shadowOffsetOuter2" result="shadowBlurOuter2" stdDeviation=".5"/><feColorMatrix in="shadowBlurOuter2" result="shadowMatrixOuter2" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.084 0"/><feMerge><feMergeNode in="shadowMatrixOuter1"/><feMergeNode in="shadowMatrixOuter2"/><feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/></feMerge></filter><rect id="b" width="38" height="38" x="5" y="5" rx="1"/></defs><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><g filter="url(#a)" transform="translate(3 3)"/><g transform="translate(-1 -1)"><use xlink:href="#b" fill="#FFF"/><use xlink:href="#b"/><use xlink:href="#b"/><use xlink:href="#b"/></g><path fill="#4285F4" d="M31.64 23.205c0-.639-.057-1.252-.164-1.841H23v3.481h4.844a4.14 4.14 0 0 1-1.796 2.716v2.259h2.908c1.702-1.567 2.684-3.875 2.684-6.615Z"/><path fill="#34A853" d="M23 32c2.43 0 4.467-.806 5.956-2.18l-2.908-2.259c-.806.54-1.837.86-3.048.86-2.344 0-4.328-1.584-5.036-3.711h-3.007v2.332A8.997 8.997 0 0 0 23 32Z"/><path fill="#FBBC05" d="M17.964 24.71a5.41 5.41 0 0 1-.282-1.71c0-.593.102-1.17.282-1.71v-2.332h-3.007A8.996 8.996 0 0 0 14 23c0 1.452.348 2.827.957 4.042l3.007-2.332Z"/><path fill="#EA4335" d="M23 17.58c1.321 0 2.508.454 3.44 1.345l2.582-2.58C27.463 14.891 25.426 14 23 14a8.997 8.997 0 0 0-8.043 4.958l3.007 2.332c.708-2.127 2.692-3.71 5.036-3.71Z"/><path d="M14 14h18v18H14V14Z"/></g></svg>
  <div class="buttonText">Sign in with Google</div>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

All it took for me was adding "line-height: 0;" to your .customBtn style definition.